# ssh without password two computers same network

Tags: linux, networking, authentication, ssh, passwords

I want to ssh between two computers on the same network with a shared file system, running Ubuntu.  This is what I did:

1. made two different rsa keys computer1_rsa.pub an computer2_rsa.pub.
2. added both of these keys to the authorized_keys file.
3. when I try and ssh back and forth I still get asked for a password. I get asked for the key passwords, not my ssh password.

How to I configure the machines so I don't have to enter in any passwords?  I'm not the admin user so I can't do anything with sudo.

Comment: I believe this question belongs to superuser or serverfault

Answer (score 1):

Add the keys to ssh-agent locally.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a key agent which caches key passwords for you. You will have to enter the password only once then.

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add path/to/keyfile # enter password

ssh machine2 # enjoy passwordless login
```

Another solution is to create the keys without password – but then make sure you keep them really safe.

Answer (score 0):

Create keys with no passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to use ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id

just like this:

```
ssh-keygen # Press enter all the way (without passphrase) will create a key at  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@192.168.1.2 #assuming other pc is 192.168.1.2
```

this will easily setup password-less login.

For more details . check it out here : http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/

Comment: keyless login? ITYM passwordless login...

Comment: sorry , yes i meant passwordless login :D , Edited